# Detecting pattern in order to show fields with more than one number in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysqli, pattern-matching, design-patterns

Imagine that you have a field with data like this (each line represents the data in that field for different rows):

```
28746: Porto Alegre
28302: Osasco
28797: Praia Grande
```

But sometimes there is more than one number in the field:

```
26755: Floriano Peixoto,26754: Floriano 25582: Bela Vista
25579: Bela Vista 25581: Bela Vista De Goiás,26867: Goiás
```

I know this data it's not normalized, but that's not the issue I want to solve.

I was wondering if it's possible to make a query that shows only the rows that have more than one number in that field.

Any suggestions on how to achieve that?

**UPDATE**

From Dark_a answer I tried this:

```
SELECT data_c1
  FROM test_data
  WHERE INSTR(data_c1,':',1,2) <> 0;
```

But it seems that INSTR only accepts to arguments:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html

However if I use this other query:

```
SELECT data_c1
  FROM test_data
  WHERE INSTR(data_c1,',') <> 0;
```

It seems to work fine, because the data in fields with more than one number, it's separeted by a comma.

Comment: My bad, sorry, I gave you example from Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT data_c1
  FROM test_data
 WHERE INSTR(data_c1,':',1,2) <> 0;
```

If comma is used in text. if not then is better to check for comma:

```
SELECT data_c1
  FROM test_data
 WHERE INSTR(data_c1,',',1,2) <> 0;
```